# Cannot set MS Office 2013 as default even with editing registry

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, windows-registry

I have been struggling trying to set MS Office 2013 as default instead of 2007 ones. My work requires to have both of them in my PC so I cannot avoid having 2007 which I hate so much on my station.

My initial issue was that I couldn't find MS 2013 on the default program list to choose from. Trying to browse the exe file didn't help either.

I followed the instructions to edit registry in this thread:
[Why won't Excel 2013 work as an "Open With..." program in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/577109/why-wont-excel-2013-work-as-an-open-with-program-in-windows-7/577136)

It seemed OK as now MS2013 appears on the ***Open With..*** list just like this:

[Open with... list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axcJr.jpg)

However, when I picked the icon of Excel 2013, my excel file still get launched by the 2007. At this point I have no idea what's the keyword to search for the solution.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try pressing start button and typing "file types"

choose "make a file type always open with a specific program"

select .xls

press change program (upper right)

Browse to new excel.  Mine is in this folder but I'm not sure about your version:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16
```

You may have to repeat for other file types.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I did so but when I finish browsing my 2013 Excel, nothing happened just like when I try to browse from "choose default program"